# How to serve Vue application over HTTPS?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, https, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to serve Vue application over HTTPS instead of HTTP.

I have tried to add --https flag to `webpack-dev-server` and add `https: true` in `build/webpack.dev.cong.js` but when I try to open the app in the browser it crashes with the following error:

```
[DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
internal/buffer.js:945
class FastBuffer extends Uint8Array {}
^

RangeError: Invalid typed array length: -4095
at new Uint8Array (<anonymous>)
```

Is there something that I missed or what is the solution for this?

And if the HTTPS properly configured to webpack devServer, after building the project it would work the same when served with web server like nginx or I have to add some reverse proxying?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this on your local machine, then you are going to want to use NGINX to serve up the HTTPS-traffic and use it to reverse proxy to whatever port on your local machine that you mount your `webpack-dev-server`. There might be a way to get Webpack to do this, but it wasn't designed to do this.

Comment: this is 100% wrong. webpack dev server is designed to generate a self-signed certificate and serve traffic over HTTPS.